# Removing light from Walgreens humidifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics

I need to remove the lights from the walgreens humidifier that I have so that I can sleep in complete darkness. However, I’m not an electrical engineer and not all that familiar with wires and circuit boards. I’m attaching the pictures below. Can you please tell me if I’m able to remove the wires from the circuit board. I think the only reason for the circuit board is for the lights which are no longer needed. Also, curious why there are three wires going into the fan part of the dehumidier since there’s no ground (it’s a two prong plug).

[image: Front of the Circuit Board]

[image: Back of the circuit Board]

[image: the knob for turning it on]

[image: back of the knob]

[image: side of the knob]

Update: Thanks for your help and thoughts! I removed the black cord for the twistable connector and cut the red cord as close as I could with scissors. I then covered the red cord with electrician's tape. See pictures. Can you make sure this won’t cause a fire or electrical hazard?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is hard to tell where all the wires go from the pictures. Could you either take more pictures showing the wires or hand draw a wiring diagram? It is ok if you don't know the names of stuff.

Comment: put black tape or aluminum tape over the lights,  no modification required

Comment: @jsotola and no voiding of warranty either.

Answer (score 4):

The red wire goes through a rectifier to change the AC voltage to DC, then a current limiting resistor which goes to the anodes (+) of the two LEDs which are in parallel, their cathodes (-) go to the black wire. There is a small capacitor across the LEDs, probably to reduce EMI. You can disconnect the red wire, the black or both  from the board. This will break the circuit and disable the LEDs. Make sure the wires aren’t exposed as they pose a shock or short circuit danger, cut them flush so no wire sticks out from the insulation and tape them with electrical tape.

As for the three wires to the fan, does it have two speed settings? If so that’s probably why three wires, one for each speed, one common.

As @jstola said, you could just tape over them, I did that on my computer, although sometimes it’s hard to block all the light.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I posted an update with pictures. Can you take a look please?

Comment: @Sam-the-man Looks like it should work.